# Pylint and pre-commit python 3.7

Tags: git, python-3.7, pylint, pre-commit.com

I am trying to set up pylint to work with pre-commit. I have looked into the docs, but still I am confused. I do not know how to setup .pre-commit-config.yaml properly.

Could you provide the most basic possible template?

```
-   repo: myrepo
    rev: ''  # Don't know that to type here
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/sebdah/git-pylint-commit-hook) will help

Comment: support up to 3.5 only

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most basic possible template would be this:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pylint
    rev: pylint-2.6.0
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
```

You can also pass arguments to pylint:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pylint
    rev: pylint-2.6.0
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
        args:
        - --max-line-length=80
        - --ignore-imports=yes
        - -d duplicate-code
```

Notes about compatibility:

- Python >=3.7 requires pylint >= 2.0
- Python 2 requires pylint < 2.0 (Python 2 support was [dropped in Pylint 2](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1763))

Comment: I just went to the website u mentioned against repo and in their `README.md` they asked to use `pylint` directly as this one is deprecated. I used pylint and created a configuration file but it's giving me error, can you help? U can see the detailed error [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/fko9i7/pylint_precommit_hook_without_the_use_of_git/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Comment: For me, it's always getting `Skipped`, What's the possible reason.

Comment: @ParvathirajanNatarajan by default it will run only on changed files, I think.
Run `pre-commit run --all-files` to confirm you can enforce the full repo scan.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a pre-commit config fragment that works for me using regular `pylint` instead of `mirrors-pylint`:

```
  - repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pylint
    rev: pylint-2.5.3
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
        args:
        - --errors-only
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Pylint's [user guide](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/installation/pre-commit-integration.html),

> Since pylint needs to import modules and dependencies to work correctly, the hook only works with a local installation of pylint (in your environment).

So you must put `repo: local` and install pylint locally. Their first example of `.pre-commit-config.yaml` looks like this:

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: pylint
      name: pylint
      entry: pylint
      language: system
      types: [python]
      args:
        [
          "-rn", # Only display messages
          "-sn", # Don't display the score
        ]
```