# Pylint setup with pre-commit In python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pylint, pre-commit.com

I was trying to set up `pylint` with `pre-commit` in my project.
I came to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023087/pylint-and-pre-commit-python-3-7) answer where they tell how to set up my `.pre-commit-config.yaml`.
When I went to the [repository](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-pylint) mentioned in the answer, they had written that

> This mirror repository is deprecated, use [pylint](https://github.com/pycqa/pylint) directly.

So I set my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file like this

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pylint
    rev: pylint-2.4.4
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
        args:
        - --limit=8
        - --rcfile=$PROJECT_ROOT/.pylintrc
```

But now when I tried to do

```
$ pre-commit run
```

It gave the following error:

```
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/Users/userabc/.cache/pre-commit/repokxyo7uuq/py_env-default/bin/python', '/Users/userabc/.cache/pre-commit/repokxyo7uuq/py_env-default/bin/pip', 'install', '.')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    Processing /Users/userabc/.cache/pre-commit/repokxyo7uuq

stderr:
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /Users/userabc/.cache/pre-commit/repokxyo7uuq/py_env-default/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gm/t0h6v8jx4bqd6cj73_k27myw0000gp/T/pip-req-build-5vjdd9f2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gm/t0h6v8jx4bqd6cj73_k27myw0000gp/T/pip-req-build-5vjdd9f2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/gm/t0h6v8jx4bqd6cj73_k27myw0000gp/T/pip-req-build-5vjdd9f2/pip-egg-info
             cwd: /private/var/folders/gm/t0h6v8jx4bqd6cj73_k27myw0000gp/T/pip-req-build-5vjdd9f2/
        Complete output (7 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/private/var/folders/gm/t0h6v8jx4bqd6cj73_k27myw0000gp/T/pip-req-build-5vjdd9f2/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
            long_description = stream.read()
          File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
            return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
        UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 4020: ordinal not in range(128)
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Check the log at /Users/userabc/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

My project and virtual environment's python version is `3.5.2`.
Is this a bug in `pylint` or `pre-commit`? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running in an environment with broken/incorrect locales set.

Search for your current locale setting by running `env | grep -E '(LC|LANG)'` and perhaps `python3 -m locale`

If configured correctly, python should be picking the `UTF-8` encoding -- usually you can correct whatever `.bashrc` / etc. is setting to an invalid locale, or you can set it yourself

A common value is: `LANG=C.UTF-8` or `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

---

EDIT: I'm also fixing pylint [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/3447)

Comment: so i did `env | grep -E '(LC|LANG)'` & the output i got is `LC_CTYPE=C`. I also ran `python3 -m locale` and I got [this](https://freetexthost.net/aKHFnvx) in output. The relevant content on my `.zshrc` is [this](https://freetexthost.net/AzOIXGr). Note that I ran those commands while being in my virtual env. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` is already there in my `.zshrc`. What am I missing here?

Comment: your zshrc isn't doing anything unless those variables are _exported_ (`export LANG=...`)

Comment: oops, sorry my bad, I did `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in `.zshrc`, tried echoing it in terminal & then ran `$ pre-commit run`, the problem persists. Same error.

Comment: that doesn't match your `python -m locale` output or your sample zshrc paste so something is missing.  can you paste fresh those outputs and your full zshrc?

Comment: this is what you should see if done correctly: https://i.fluffy.cc/3LKjLq4w4LwXpkvtr4sVPlmVxv5zf7mB.html

Comment: seems to have worked, very nice. I am accepting the answer. In case you have time, can you please tell me how did u reach this solution? I am unable to connect the dots.

Comment: I've seen the same symptoms many many times -- python determines the default locale via the environment, if it's not found it uses ascii -- the README contains UTF-8 encoded characters (not-ascii)

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all use the below command.

   ```
   pip install -U setuptools
   ```

   or simply you may create new Virtual Environment.
2. Then manually run the pre-commit to confirm the configurations.

   ```
   pre-commit run --all-files
   ```

   Then you may finalize the pylint configurations like

repo:  https://github.com/pycqa/pylint

```
rev: pylint-2.4.4
hooks:
-   id: pylint
    args:
    - --max-line-length=80
    - --ignore-imports=yes
    - -d duplicate-code
```